# Redirect URL without trailing post id using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a scenario where I need to redirect all URLs or wordpress without trailing post id using .htaccess

Example:

https://example.com/chapter/subject-origin-chapter/1223 to https://example.com/chapter/subject-origin-chapter

and

https://example.com/subject/subject-physics/38957 to https://example.com/subject/subject-physics

Other solutions are also welcome.

**Current .htaccess is:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share your htaccess rules fiile which you are having right now with you in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 its usual wordpress .htaccess without any addition. However let me add this to my question.

Comment: Just `RewriteRule ^((chapter|subject)/.*)/[0-9]+ $1 [R=301,L]` should do the trick. To be placed before the general WP rewrites of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution as:

```
RewriteRule ^chapter/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(\d+)$ /chapter/$1 [L, R=301]
RewriteRule ^subject/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(\d+)$ /subject/$1 [L, R=301]
```